# How to encrypt a URL in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, url, encryption, backbone.js

In Backbone.js we use a router to specify a url format and to specify the page to redirect to.

For example:

```
"serviceslist/:id/:serviceId": "serviceslist",
```

---

```
serviceslist: function(id, serviceId) {
    var self = this;
    this.load();
    require([
        'js/views/patient/serviceslist'
    ], function(serviceslist) {
        self.shell();
        if (typeof app.serviceslist !== 'undefined') {
            app.serviceslist.destroy();
        }
        app.serviceslist = new serviceslist({ Id: id, fromouter: false, serviceId: serviceid });
        $("#main-nav li.active").removeClass("active");
        $("#admin").addClass("active");
    });
},
```

we call in js:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('#/serviceslist/1456/false/1111', { trigger: true });
```

the link will be:

```
http://localhost:64865/#/serviceslist/1456/false/1111
```

Is there a way to encrypt this part of the url: `1456/false/1111`?

Comment: Since Backbone is client side, any encryption is pointless since everything is already in the hand of the user before any operation can be done. Do you really mean encryption and not encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your route parts that need to be escaped.

Example:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('Time &time=again'));
console.log('#/serviceslist/' + encodeURIComponent('1456&123/456') + '/false/1111')
```

So your navigate code could be:

```
var id = '1456/false';
var serviceId = '1111';

Backbone.history.navigate('#/serviceslist/' + encodeURIComponent(id) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(serviceId), { trigger: true });
```

You may need to decode it on the router though:

```
serviceslist: function (id,serviceId) {
    // decode the route params :id & :serviceId
    id = decodeURIComponent(id);
    serviceId = decodeURIComponent(serviceId);
    // the rest of your logic here
}
```

Comment: this method encodeURIComponent doesn't encrypt int values :S

Comment: Oh... I see.. you need a way to "hide" it from the users. You need to obfuscate this in some other way, but ultimately, are those ids that sensitive? Perhaps you need to use something else if you need the users to not try to guess the ids, if that's what you are after. For example use a "slug" aka a generated string based on the service's name, instead of the service's id. eg: my-aswsome-service-one, my-awesome-service-two. These should be unique so you could retrieve the record and find its id. And of course stored on the backend

Comment: @Lili This answer provides a way to encode, which is not encryption.

Comment: Yes... I assumed she was wrongly referring to encoding as encryption. I've seen that happen and that's the most common use for an URL, hence provided the answer for that.